# Different templates for one content (KeystoneJS / Node)

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Is it possible to select different template (i.e. twig template) for same content type?

An Example: 
3 blog posts, each displayed using different template...? 
Template selected from a dropdown list during blog post creation?

Answer (score 0):

use mixin

```
  mixin different_blog_view_type(type)
  ....
  if type !== "view1"
    .supacoolEl23
  .....
  if type === "view2"
    #moreCoolest2view
```

Don't forget to define locals.type variable, and change it your preferred way (dropdown,radio, so on)

```
  exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;
    locals.type = req.params.type; 
    //this wil get from :type param
    //or you can use req.body or req.query
```